# How do I assign a function key to execute a string of commands?

Tags: python, function, printing, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I'm not sure if this is a setting in Windows or not - if it is, they've done a great job at hiding it - but I'm trying to program a function key (or some other key(s) like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or something) to quick print.

To be very specific, I am looking to bypass the two-step process or (ctrl+p) + (enter) in a program called Bluebeam Revu (a pdf viewing/editing program) by simply pressing one button that does both of those steps for me - I essentially want to bypass the (enter) step. I'm very new to programming, just a week or so into learning Python, but I feel like there's got to be a way to do this, whether it be to set up a program that runs in the background, reassign a combination of keys to do this, or do something with the code of Bluebeam.

Comment: Take a look at `pyautogui` and/or`pynput`.